# laravel model - how to dynamically set a column value in the Model?

Tags: laravel

When a User is created, e.g. with the following line in a controller:

```
$user = $this->create($request->all());
```

This will insert a user record with the form values (name, email, password etc).

But if we want to set a "hidden" user fields/colums on the model and DB table, e.g. a special unique generated token (user.token), We dont want to do this in every controller.

If laravel had a service layer, it could be done here, but better would be to do it in the model itself.

e.g. by catching a beforeSave callback, and having some code generate the token and set the corresponding field before it gets written to the DB. I see that the model has saved() event/observers, but this looks like it happens after the save, and I dont want to put this logic in an external class, It belongs in the model, and the documenation doesnt say if the observer can modify the model (by setting columns in this case)

Any suggestions?

Comment: You mean implement a setter for a column which will always be set, e.g. name, and put code in there to set other columns, such as token? Its a bit of a hack, but might work...

Comment: It's also worth noting that just because an attribute is hidden, it doesn't mean that it's not fillable. Just add it to your `fillable` array, and/or remove it from your `guarded` array.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to define event listeners directly within your model. E.g. add a `boot` method to your `User` model:

```
/**
 * Define model event callbacks.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::saving(function ($model) {
        $model->token = str_random(60);
    });
}
```

Alternative, more verbose implementation:

```
/**
 * Define model event callbacks.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::saving(function ($model) {
        if (method_exists($model, 'beforeSave')) $model->beforeSave();
    });
}

/**
 * Before save event listener.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function beforeSave()
{
    $this->token = str_random(60);
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. If i put a function say "beforeSave()" in my model, could I call this via your boot method?  so the model logic is in one place (future devs will never find it in boot).  This would then be similar to grails. In grails, I can just add methods to the model (such as "beforeUpdate" which are called automatically.  thx.

Comment: If future devs are using Laravel, one would hope they look at how _that_ framework implements events, rather than assuming it'll be similar to a different language/framework. These are the [available events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#events) in Eloquent models. You can use these, or write your own event layer if you prefer.